# how to know which domain is using which apache instance

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd

I have a vps with DirectAdmin installed on it. today my server went down for an hour and when I checked the notification center I saw that some of the httpd instance are using a lot of my cpu power.
you can check a part top command below.
what I want to know is which one of my domains are causing this?

`top` command result:

> top - 07:52:54 up 21:08,  0 users,  load average: 61.00, 19.79, 6.98
>   Tasks: 223 total,   5 running, 218 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
>   Cpu(s):  3.7%us,  0.3%sy,  0.0%ni, 95.6%id,  0.3%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,
>   0.0%st Mem:   1026200k total,  1014088k used,    12112k free,      764k buffers Swap:  3002360k total,  1166920k used,  1835440k free,
>   14084k cached
>
> PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
>   12684 apache    20   0 55192  15m 1044 D  2.9  1.5   0:01.10
>   /usr/sbin/httpd -k start -DSSL
>   12660 apache    20   0 50248  15m 1324 D  2.7  1.6   0:01.13
>   /usr/sbin/httpd -k start -DSSL
>   10782 apache    20   0 58860  15m 1456 R  2.5  1.5   0:37.45
>   /usr/sbin/httpd -k start -DSSL
>   12686 apache    20   0 55144  17m 1044 D  2.2  1.7   0:01.04
>   /usr/sbin/httpd -k start -DSSL
>   28 root      20   0     0    0    0 R  2.0  0.0   0:00.60 [kswapd0]
>   12654 apache    20   0 55144  14m 1044 D  2.0  1.5   0:01.03
>   /usr/sbin/httpd -k start -DSSL
>   12658 apache    20   0 55144  11m 1044 D  2.0  1.1   0:00.94
>   /usr/sbin/httpd -k start -DSSL
>   12669 apache    20   0 55144  18m 1044 D  1.7  1.8   0:01.03
>   /usr/sbin/httpd -k start -DSSL
>   12695 apache    20   0 55144  18m 1044 D  1.7  1.8   0:01.05
>   /usr/sbin/httpd -k start -DSSL
>   12681 apache    20   0 55176  15m 1044 D  1.5  1.5   0:00.94
>   /usr/sbin/httpd -k start -DSSL
>   12670 apache    20   0 55184  13m 1044 D  1.2  1.3   0:00.85
>   /usr/sbin/httpd -k start -DSSL
>   12692 apache    20   0 55144  16m 1044 D  1.0  1.7   0:01.00
>   /usr/sbin/httpd -k start -DSSL
>   12696 apache    20   0 55144  19m 1044 D  1.0  1.9   0:01.00
>   /usr/sbin/httpd -k start -DSSL
>   12700 apache    20   0 56304 7296 1028 D  1.0  0.7   0:00.79
>   /usr/sbin/httpd -k start -DSSL
>   12719 apache    20   0 54812  11m 1216 S  0.7  1.2   0:00.60
>   /usr/sbin/httpd -k start -DSSL
>   12734 apache    20   0 54804  12m 1212 R  0.7  1.3   0:00.62
>   /usr/sbin/httpd -k start -DSSL
>   12772 apache    20   0 54812  20m 1724 R  0.7  2.1   0:00.63
>   /usr/sbin/httpd -k start -DSSL

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by the previous answer, looking at a specific Apache process doesn't have a lot of value.

I might suggest that you should alter your httpd.conf settings - either using more efficient processes (e.g. PHP-FPM instead of mod_php) or altering the number of servers/clients/requests).

Typically, in an environment with multiple domains, each domain gets it own user. (This is typically seen if you are running PHP in FastCGI mode, and makes it easy to see which PHP process is using significant resources).

The following is simply for interest sake - it serves little useful purpose in this case:

Should you really want to determine what site a particular process is serving at any given instant, you could run a trace looking for file access. Be advised however, that significant quantities of output will generated very rapidly on a high traffic server.

For instance, the following will show file opens (typically only .htaccess files if you use FastCGI), as well as directory listings, and is enough to identify which domain the process is serving right now:

`strace -p PID -e trace=open,lstat64`

Example Output:

```
Process PID attached - interrupt to quit
open("/path/to/website/folder/.htaccess", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFIL     E|O_CLOEXEC) = 66
open("/path/to/website/folder/subfolder/.htaccess", O_RDONLY|O     _LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
lstat64("/path", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat64("/path/to", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=90, ...}) = 0
lstat64("/path/to/website", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat64("/path/to/website/folder", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, .     ..}) = 0
lstat64("/path/to/website/folder/subfolder", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0750, st_size     =21, ...}) = 0
lstat64("/path/to/website/folder/subfolder/php.fcgi", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0750     , st_size=96, ...}) = 0
```

Alternatively, you can look at the process reads, and grep for 'Host':

`strace -p PID -e trace=read -s 100 2>&1 | grep "Host:"`

Example Output:

```
read(65, "GET /path/of/request/ HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: www.domain.com\r\nX-Real-IP: xxx.xxx.xxx.xx"..., 8000) = 1167
```

(You might need to make the 'string length' (s) value longer)

Once again, keep in mind that both of these are an 'instant in time' look at what a given process is serving - in the next instant that will change - it is therefore useless for anything beyond curiosity.

Answer (score 2):

The processes you are looking at in the top output reflect how many daemons have spawned to handle HTTP/S requests to your server. They are not explicitly linked to a particular website. When a request comes to your server an idle daemon will take the request and based on the header information sent to the server, it will then connect it to the correct file.

In short, none of the processes are explicitly linked to a particular site, but all of them are potentially linked to it.

Regards,
Phil,

Answer (score 1):

netstat -tp will tell you which process is serving which TCP connection, allowing you to map processes to hostnames.

that said, you'd be better off using Apache's mod_status (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_status.html), as it's built specifically for this problem.

It doesn't look like CPU is your issue here, though.  You've got 12M of free memory, and you're dipping heavily into swap.

Comment: yes, you're right. my problem was with with the number apache instanced initiated. I just set the MaxClients and ServerLimit directives to 15 and i'm waiting for what's to come next.